# Using mysqldump to backup database to file with full data

Tags: linux, database, backup, mysql

I'm trying to use mysqldump to backup my databases - data and all. I can use this command to dump the data on the command line:

```
mysqldump -u username -ppassword --skip-lock-tables --databases database
```

That works great, and I have a full mass insert statement with all the data. if I do this however:

```
mysqldump -u username -ppassword --skip-lock-tables --databases database  > /var/backup/$(date +\%d-\%m-\%Y)_dump.sql
```

to add the output to a file (I've checked that the file name scheme works), I only get the create and update commands, and one row of data for each table. I've also tried this without --skip-lock-tables, but I wanted to make sure this wasn't a problem with getting a lock. This will eventually go into a cron job, so I'd like to be able to keep this to one line if possible.

The output on the command line is quite long, but here is an example of part of the mass insert statement:

```
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `clients` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `clients` VALUES (1,'nicholas','sallis','it@konditormeister.com','11 hunnewell circle ','newton','02458','ma','7818491970','2016-05-10 16:17:55','2016-05-10 16:17:55')
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Are you wondering if you should be using --skip-lock-tables?

Comment: no, I want to know why I am not getting any data when I divert to a file. I get the create, update... statements, but no mass insertion like I do when I output to the command line.

Comment: Would you report briefly what prints out on your terminal (not in the backup file) when you try "mysqldump -u username -ppassword -v --databases database > /var/backup/$(date +\%d-\%m-\%Y)_dump.sql"?

Comment: I get the same as before with the addition of this in the command line: `connecting to localhost ... Retrieving table structure for table TABLENAME... Sending SELECT query... ... -- Retrieving rows...